# Quiero ejecutar un comando al iniciar mi terminal, ¿Que hago?

Tags: linux, terminal

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow quisiera que al iniciar mi terminal en ubuntu este iniciado este comando directamente `neofetch` ya que es el que me indica mucho como esta mi sistema.

Comment: @NaCl Gracias me sirvio era sencillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edita el archivo `~/.bashrc` poniendo el nombre del ejecutable.

Si no existe, lo creas y debe funcionar igual.